# How to modify HttpContext in ActionExecutionContext to deny the request with a body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, action-filter

The ActionExecutionContext is defined in a [ActionFilter attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Example:

```
 internal class TestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {

         context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;

         //context.HttpContext.Response.Body 
     }
 }
```

How do you make the response of the [ActionExecutionContext's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.httpcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ControllerContext_HttpContext) have status code 400 (Bad Request), and to also have a body of for example "You have no access."

In ASP.NET you could easily do this with the following code:

```
HttpActionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
   Content = "You have no access.";
}
```

You can define the status code by using

```
ActionExecutionContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
```

but what about the contents, and is this really the best approach - to manually write in the status code number?

Comment: It's not in a controller, it's part of an action filter. Aren't ActionExecutionContext only used there? I'll clarify just in case.

Comment: I think you can use methods on `Response` property e.g. `Response.ClearContent();` and `Response.Write("You have no access.");`

Comment: Is it `context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("You have no access.");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [dropoutcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8442437/dropoutcoder) and [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd), both approaches are valid and work perfectly!

```
internal class TestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Suggested by dropoutcoder
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("You have no access").Wait();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;

        // Suggested by stuartd
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("You have no access");
    }
}
```